# Returning parameters from new window

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, popup

What I want is to open a new popup from the server side, this pop up has a form with three fields, and then return this three fields to the parent page. But I want this fields in the server side, in the VB.NET code. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible to open a popup from the server side code. You have to open it in the browser.

Comment: It is possible using JavaScript. I can open a popup from the server side but I can't retrieve parameters from it

Comment: You can't use Javacript from the server side code, the Javascript runs in the browser. Thus, you can't use the result from the popup in the same server code that creates the Javascript, as it runs in the browser after the server code is completed.

Comment: I know. I was saying that I can open a popup from server side using this: Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { openPopup();}</script>") for example. I know that this code is from the client side but I can use it from the VB part. You understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a modal popup window acceptable? If so, you could put the variables in an update panel, and use the server side event of the button that causes a postback on the modal to force the the update panel to update.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a form to show as popup
- Display it
- - Perform a POST request onto the parent form to pass the values
- - *or*
- - save input into Session vaariable and read it on popup close

Comment: Also see [ASP.NET wiki entry](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/282/passing-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-form39s-textbox/)

Comment: Ok but if I show the popup and I do the post, I get the post page in the popup window instead of in the parent window.. :S